# How to insert or update records in multiple tables in oracle from java using spring jdbc template in one network call

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I need to insert records in `table A`, update records in `table B`, delete records in `table c` from java using spring jdbc template. Can I do all of these operations in single sql query(one network call)?. I am using oracle database, java 1.8, Spring jdbc template, spring version 4.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do the three sql at the same transaction, you can use org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional to controller your rollback, make sure do all this operations at the same transaction

```
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
public void executeSQL() {
  insert records in table A
  update records in table B
  delete records in table c
}
```